# how can find the value of a row based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
user-id     time    location   msg  path
  1           1         1       1    0
  2           1         1       2    1000
  3           1         2       3    1
  4           1         2       0    0
  5           1         3       0    0
  1           2         2       2    0
  2           2         1       1    1
  3           2         1       1    1
  4           2         0       0    0
  5           2         0       0    0
  1           3         1       3    0
  2           3         3       1    0
```

I want to find the path based on the maximum number of msg where the time and the location are the same for two records.

```
time_locs = pd.unique(df['time_loc'])
for time_loc in time_locs:
   dc_group = df[df['time_loc'] == time_loc]
   if(len(dc_group) > 1):
        max_num_msg = max(dc_group['msgs'])
```

So I zipped the time and location as time_loc and found the maximum number of msges. Now how can I found the path of that row?

For example, in this case my first dc-group is  this two rows:

```
user-id     time    location   msg  path
  1           1         1       1    0
  2           1         1       2    1000
```

I want to find 1000.

I tried this code but it is not working.

```
user_group = df.loc[max(dc_group['msgs']), 'path']
```

because it is searching in all df. And .loc is not working for dc_group, it mean this code face error:

```
user_group = dc_group.loc[max(dc_group['msgs']), 'path']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to use non-looping approaches here. You can use `.argmax` to get the index of the maximum value instead of the value itself. Something like:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
    user-id  time  location  msg  path
0         1     1         1    1     0
1         2     1         1    1     0
2         3     1         2    0     0
3         4     1         2    0     0
4         5     1         3    0     0
5         1     2         2    2     0
6         2     2         1    1     0
7         3     2         1    1     0
8         4     2         0    0     0
9         5     2         0    0     0
10        1     3         1    3     0
11        2     3         3    1     0

In [16]: df.loc[df.time == df.location, 'msg'].argmax()
Out[16]: 5

In [17]: max_idx = df.loc[df.time == df.location, 'msg'].argmax()

In [18]: df.loc[max_idx]
Out[18]:
user-id     1
time        2
location    2
msg         2
path        0
Name: 5, dtype: int64

In [19]: df.loc[max_idx, 'path']
Out[19]: 0
```

If you want all the rows, then just use boolean indexing:

```
In [25]: df.loc[df.time == df.location]
Out[25]:
    user-id  time  location  msg  path
0         1     1         1    1     0
1         2     1         1    1     0
5         1     2         2    2     0
11        2     3         3    1     0
```

Or `.query` if you prefer:

```
In [26]: df.query('time == location')
Out[26]:
    user-id  time  location  msg  path
0         1     1         1    1     0
1         2     1         1    1     0
5         1     2         2    2     0
11        2     3         3    1     0
```

Comment: Your right. But I don't want a single row I want the rows that their time and location are the same, not just one that its time and location is same.

Comment: @Elham then use boolean indexing... I don't understand what you don't understand.

Comment: @Elham then what *do* you want. You stated "I want to change the path based on the maximum number of msg where the time and the location are the same for two records."

Comment: I need to work with for loop and then I need to work with the dc_group that I create. Then in each dc_group find the maximum number and find the path.

Comment: @Elham can you please describe with an example output what you are trying to accomplish. It is very unclear.

Comment: I have changed the question again to make it clear. Sry about confusing.